# check if two columns are identical for per group after group by

Tags: mysql

Assuming a database has two tables:

## 1.Table SC:

```
+------+------+-------+
| sid  | cid  | score |
+------+------+-------+
| 01   | 01   |  80.0 |
| 01   | 02   |  90.0 |
| 01   | 03   |  99.0 |
| 02   | 01   |  70.0 |
| 02   | 02   |  60.0 |
| 02   | 03   |  80.0 |
| 03   | 01   |  80.0 |
| 03   | 02   |  80.0 |
| 03   | 03   |  80.0 |
| 04   | 01   |  50.0 |
| 04   | 02   |  30.0 |
| 04   | 03   |  20.0 |
| 05   | 01   |  76.0 |
| 05   | 02   |  87.0 |
| 06   | 01   |  31.0 |
| 06   | 03   |  34.0 |
| 07   | 02   |  89.0 |
| 07   | 03   |  98.0 |
+------+------+-------+
```

sid is student id, cid is course id, score is just score.

```
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid   | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| cid   | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| score | decimal(18,1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

## 2.Table student:

```
+------+-------+---------------------+------+
| sid  | sname | dob                 | ssex |
+------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 01   | Amy   | 1990-01-01 00:00:00 | M    |
| 02   | Bob   | 1990-12-21 00:00:00 | M    |
| 03   | Cath  | 1990-05-20 00:00:00 | M    |
| 04   | Dick  | 1990-08-06 00:00:00 | M    |
| 05   | Ella  | 1991-12-01 00:00:00 | F    |
| 06   | Geroge| 1992-03-01 00:00:00 | F    |
| 07   | Froth | 1989-07-01 00:00:00 | F    |
| 08   | Hue   | 1990-01-20 00:00:00 | F    |
+------+-------+---------------------+------+
```

with

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sid   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sname | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sage  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ssex  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

## Question:

return the sid and sname of those who have registered exactly the same courses
as student with sid '01'?

for example, From SC table, we can see that student with sid '01' register course 01,02,03. sid 02,03,04 also register the same course.
Thus we need to return

```
+------+-------+
| sid  | sname |
+------+-------+
| 02   | Bob   |
| 03   | Cath  |
| 04   | Dick  |
+------+-------+
```

I have no idea how to do that and I am not sure if there exist some elegant solutions like:

```
SELECT sid, sname from student
where sid in
( select distinct sid from SC
  group by sid
  having cid = (select distinct cid from SC where sid = '01')
);
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: _Small Note_ Can I suggest you make your `sid` and `cid` columns into INTEGERS as they seem to contain integers anyway

Comment: _Small Note_ if columns `sage` stands for Student Age, then maybe rename it `DOB` and make it into a `DATE`type and not a `DATETIME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this query:

```
select sid from sc
group by sid
having 
  sum(cid in (select cid from sc where sid = '01')) = 
  (select count(*) from sc where sid = '01')
  and
  sum(cid not in (select cid from sc where sid = '01')) = 0
```

you get the ids of all the students matching your conditions. 
Then join it to the table `student`:

```
select s.sid, s.sname 
from student s inner join (
    select sid from sc
    group by sid
    having 
      sum(cid in (select cid from sc where sid = '01')) = 
      (select count(*) from sc where sid = '01')
      and
      sum(cid not in (select cid from sc where sid = '01')) = 0
) g on g.sid = s.sid
where s.sid <> '01'
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for!